# What is the purpose of Mocha's before() function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

Mocha has several 'hooks' to run assistive functionality in a test separate from the test cases themselves (clearing databases, creating mock files, etc).

However, in the case of `before()` (**not** `beforeEach()`, that one I get), it seems pretty redundant.

`before()` runs the logic *once* before all of the tests in the current suite, so why do I need to even wrap it in a function?

There's no observable difference between the two following:

```
describe('Something', function() {
    before(doSomePreTestLogic);
    //Tests ahoy
});
```

and

```
describe('Something', function() {
    doSomePreTestLogic();
    //Tests ahoy
});
```

What's the point of wrapping my pre-test logic with `before()`?

Comment: AFAIK, Jasmine doesn't even have `before()`, which furthers the thought that this function is useless...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a couple different reasons why you might opt for the `before()` hook in your tests:

**Semantics**

This is probably the biggest one.  Sometimes you may need to perform a task, such as populate some dummy data in your database, prior to running an actual test.  You can certainly do that in the test itself, but that throws off your reporting if you encounter an error while pre-populating, and before having run the actual test case at all.  By having a `before()` hook, you have a logical, semantically valid place to insert this kind of logic.

**Cleaner for Async Tests**

Just like mocha tests can be asynchronous, so can your `before()` hook logic.  Going back to the pre-population example, this is handy since that means all of your async pre-test logic won't force another level of indentation on all of your actual testing logic.

**Consistency with other hooks:**

Mocha also provides several other hooks, namely: `after()`, `beforeEach()`, and `afterEach()`.  You could probably ask this same question about all these other hooks as well, but if you buy into the notion that any of them have a validated existence, then `before()` really needs to be included to round out the API.

Answer (score 6):

#### The Upshot

Put directly inside a `describe` callback code that will *build* the test suite. I'm talking about calls to `it` but also functions that may loop over tables or files to declare a bunch of tests (by calling `it` in the loop).

Put inside hooks the code that actually initialize the *state that the tests depend on.*

All other considerations are quite secondary.

Let me explain...

#### The Background

Mocha executes a test suite in two phases:

1. It discovers what tests exist. During this phase it will *immediately* execute the callbacks passed to `describe` and record for *future invocation* the callbacks passed to the functions that declare tests (`it` and the like) and functions that declare hooks (`before`, `beforeEach`, `after`, etc.).
2. It runs the tests. In this phase it will run the callbacks that it recorded earlier.

#### The Difference

So consider this example:

```
function dump () { console.log("running:", this.test.fullTitle()); }
describe("top", function () {
    before(dump);
    it("test 1", dump);
    it("test 2", dump);
    describe("level 1", function () {
        before(dump);
        it("test 1", dump);
        it("test 2", dump);
    });
});
```

Note that `fullTitle` gives the whole name of a test starting from the top level `describe`, going through any nested `describe` down to the `it` or hook that contains the call. Run with the `spec` reporter and keeping only the `running:` lines, you get:

```
running: top "before all" hook: dump
running: top test 1
running: top test 2
running: top level 1 "before all" hook: dump
running: top level 1 test 1
running: top level 1 test 2
```

Note the order of the hooks, and how **each executes immediately before the tests declared in its respective `describe` callback.**

Consider then this suite:

```
function dump () { console.log("running:", this.test.fullTitle()); }
function directDump() { console.log("running (direct):", this.fullTitle()); }
describe("top", function () {
    directDump.call(this);
    it("test 1", dump);
    it("test 2", dump);
    describe("level 1", function () {
        directDump.call(this);
        it("test 1", dump);
        it("test 2", dump);
    });
});
```

Run with the `spec` reporter and keeping only the `running:` lines, you get:

```
running (direct): top
running (direct): top level 1
running: top test 1
running: top test 2
running: top level 1 test 1
running: top level 1 test 2
```

Note how **both calls to `directDump` are run before anything else.**

#### The Consequences

1. If any initialization code that you put directly inside a callback to `describe` fails, **the entire run fails right away**. No test will be executed. End of story.
2. If any initialization code that you put inside a `before` hook fails, **the consequences are contained.** For one thing, because a `before` hook is run just at the moment is needed, there is an opportunity any tests that are scheduled earlier can run. Also, Mocha will only skip those tests that depend on the `before` hook. For instance, let's assume this suite:

   ```
   function dump () { console.log("running:", this.test.fullTitle()); }
   describe("top", function () {
       before(dump);
       it("test 1", dump);
       it("test 2", dump);
       describe("level 1", function () {
           before(function () { throw new Error("foo"); });
           it("test 1", dump);
           it("test 2", dump);
       });

       describe("level 1 (second)", function () {
           before(dump);
           it("test 1", dump);
           it("test 2", dump);
       });
   });
   ```

   If you run it with the `spec` reporter, the entire output (minus the stack trace) will be something like:

   ```
     top
   running: top "before all" hook: dump
   running: top test 1
       ✓ test 1
   running: top test 2
       ✓ test 2
       level 1
         1) "before all" hook
       level 1 (second)
   running: top level 1 (second) "before all" hook: dump
   running: top level 1 (second) test 1
         ✓ test 1
   running: top level 1 (second) test 2
         ✓ test 2


     4 passing (5ms)
     1 failing

     1) top level 1 "before all" hook:
        Error: foo
        [stack trace]
   ```

   Note how a) some tests ran before the failing hook and b) Mocha still ran the tests that do not depend on the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Semantics, at both the machine and human level.

Also, it keeps test code in line with the "exports" interface, e.g.,

```
module.exports = {
  before: function(){
    // ...
  },

  'Array': {
    '#indexOf()': {
      'should return -1 when not present': function(){
        [1,2,3].indexOf(4).should.equal(-1);
      }
    }
  }
};
```