# Getting dynamic "it"s to work based on array defined in "before" in mochajs?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Does anyone know how to accomplish something like this:

```
describe('dynamic array test', function(){
    var checks;
    before(function(){
        checks = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            checks[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        }
    });
    for(var check in checks){
        it("check #" + check, function(){
            expect(checks[check]).to.equal(1);
        });
    }
});
```

Basically I have an array I generate in the before that I want the "it" output to reflect and then execute.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* generate tests in a loop but the code that *generates* the tests (i.e. that calls `it`) cannot depend on the result of a computation performed in a hook like `before`. (Note here I said that the code that **generates** the test cannot depend on a computation performed in a hook. The code **in** the tests can depend on a computation performed in a hook.) The reason is due to how Mocha discovers and executes your tests, which I've explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26309192/1906307).

You can do something like this:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('dynamic array test', function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        it("check #" + i, function(){
            expect(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)).to.equal(1);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have looks fine, but you might need to update this:

```
for(var check in checks){
    it("check #" + check, function(){
        expect(checks[check]).to.equal(1);
    })
}
```

to

```
for(var check in checks){
    (function () {
        it("check #" + check, function(){
            expect(checks[check]).to.equal(1);
        })
    })()
}
```

To ensure the proper value of *check* is used in each test.

Comment: The for loop is getting run as soon as describe is, which means the arr is empty because before hasn't run yet.

Comment: Just put the checks outside the describe instead? Or put them in separate modules (aka files) and require them?