# Mocha using for loop for data driven test always runs last iteration

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Using three scripts. Trying to read data from excel, assign it to global variable which can be accessed by all the test scripts. Want to run test for each iteration of for loop but it always goes to last iteration.

Trial.js

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var other_script = require('./MyTest.js');
var global_var = require('./Global_Setup').Setup;

describe ('Test Suite', function() {

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    global_var.testRow = i;
    //read data for row 1 and set it in global_var variables
    Call_Test(i);
}
});

function Call_Test (i) {

            console.log('i = ' + i);
            other_script.Form.FormLogin();
}
```

MyTest.js

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var global_var = require('./Global_Setup').Setup;


var Form = {

FormLogin: function () {

   describe ('Loop Suite', function() {
        it('Loop', function () {
            console.log('row index!!' + global_var.testRow);
            //done();
        });
    });

}

};

module.exports.Form = Form;
```

Global_Setup.js

```
var Setup =
 {
   testRow: '',

};
module.exports.Setup = Setup;
```

Output for Loop Suite is:

row index!!1

row index!!1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha will execute *your entire loop* before it starts running any test. So when your loop is over, `global_var.testRow` has the latest value set by the loop, and then your tests start and they all read the same value. (I have a [general explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26309192/1906307) of the order in which Mocha executes test code.)

Instead of relying on global variables, pass the value you want each test to use. Here's an example:

New `Trial.js`:

```
var other_script = require('./MyTest.js');

describe ('Test Suite', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //read data for row 1 and set it in global_var variables
        Call_Test(i);
    }
});

function Call_Test (i) {
    console.log('i = ' + i);
    // Pass the value here.
    other_script.Form.FormLogin(i);
}
```

New `MyTest.js`:

```
var Form = {
    // Accept a parameter here.
    FormLogin: function (i) {
        describe ('Loop Suite', function() {
            it('Loop', function () {
                console.log('row index!! ' + i);
                //done();
            });
        });
    }
};

exports.Form = Form;
```

Note that you don't need to import `mocha` into your test files. And the `Global_Setup.js` file is no longer necessary with the code above.

I've modified `FormLogin` to accept a parameter, and `Call_Test` now calls `FormLogin` with this parameter.

Here is the output I get:

```
i = 0
i = 1


  Test Suite
    Loop Suite
row index!! 0
      ✓ Loop
    Loop Suite
row index!! 1
      ✓ Loop


  2 passing (19ms)
```

Comment: thank you. other_script.Form.FormLogin(i); If I have another script which reads second tab in excel then I have to pass personal_info_script.Form.FormPersonalInfo(i) and read data from second tab. If I have third script which uses some of data from first tab and reads columns from third tab based on data in first tab for that row ... I have to read both first and third tab in third script. I am trying to avoid reading tabs multiple times from excel for a test suite.